# If $x_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence and $|x_n| < 1+\dfrac{1}{n}$ then $x_n$ converges to $1$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Even though $x_n$ is bounded above by $1$ it does not necessarily converge to $1$, right?

For example $x_n = -\dfrac{1}{n}$ which is increasing and bounded above by  $1+\dfrac{1}{n}$ but in tends to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

What change I can do for the conjecture to be true? Shall I replace $<$ with $\leq$ ?

Comment: Perhaps $x_n \ge 1$ ?

Comment: @DanielV yeah $1$ as a lower bound would do. Thank you!

Comment: the only sequence satisfying the original hypothesis and also $x_n\ge1$ is $x_n=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. If you want to use squeeze theorem to conclude the limit to be $1$, you need a lower bound for the sequence. For example:

$$1\le x_n$$

So you have $$1\le |x_n|<1+\frac{1}n$$

then you can use squeeze theorem

Comment: Yep thank you for the answer!

Comment: If $1\le|x_n|<1+\frac1n$ and $|x_n|$ is increasing then $|x_n|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is not unique. For example, you can set $x_n = \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\cos(\frac{\pi}{n})$ or $x_n \ge 1$ as in the comment above and either one is an increasing sequence and converges to $1$ and both satisfy the condition $|x_n| < 1+\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Ah yeah.$1$ as a lower bound is the key. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

More general condition:

$|x_n| < 1+\dfrac{1}{n}$

Implies $\lim |x_n|\le 1$

Since $(x_n) $ is increasing , $1$ is an upper bound of the range set $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$

Then $x_n\to 1 \iff \sup\{x_n:n\in\Bbb{N}\}=1$

So it is enough to find a subsequence of $(x_n) $ that converges to $1$.

Comment: Thank you! Got the idea